# Angular Material Selection List - Disabled options can be selected/deselected by keyboard

Tags: angular-material

I have a list of items that get disabled on init depending on users settings. It was just pointed out to me that you can navigate via keyboard and select/deselect items that are otherwise disabled. See : 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-m5gtdy

is this a bug, or am I missing something?

```
  <mat-selection-list required >
   <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before">EU
   </mat-list-option>
   <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" disabled=“true”>US
   </mat-list-option>
   <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before">CA
   </mat-list-option>
 </mat-selection-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like a bug but here's a possible (hacky?) solution - [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material2-issue-5vq9da?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts)

Component

```
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  version = VERSION;
  @ViewChild('selectionList') selectionList: MatSelectionList;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.selectionList.selectionChange.subscribe((value: MatSelectionListChange) => {
      if (value.option.disabled) {
        value.option.selected = !value.option.selected;
      }
    })
  }
}
```

Markup

```
<mat-selection-list required #selectionList>
   <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before">EU
   </mat-list-option>
   <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before" [disabled]="true">US
   </mat-list-option>
   <mat-list-option checkboxPosition="before">CA
   </mat-list-option>
</mat-selection-list>
```

The idea is to toggle back to it's original value any changes to a disabled option. Note that `[disabled]` is used to set the Input value.

Comment: Hours of thought put into that, and you hacked it in no time. It does look like Material is fixing the bug, so thats a happy note. But since this works for now I thank you very much.